# Exception when trying to reference Azure Analysis Service Tabular Model C#

Tags: c#, azure, ssas, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

The problem I get is an exception when I try to reference Azure Analysis Service Tabular Model.

Message=The value '2' is unexpected for type 'DataSourceType'.
Source=
StackTrace:
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ObjectFactory.CreateDataSourceFromRowset(IPropertyReader reader)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.DdlUtil.LoadDataTable(ObjectType objectType, DataTable table, DictionaryobjectMap, StringComparerInfo comparerInfo)

I found the same problem here [Exception when referencing SSAS Tabular model in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296949/exception-when-referencing-ssas-tabular-model-in-c-sharp) but there is no solution for it.

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Database db = 
SSASConnection.Instance(Parent.Name).Databases.Find(Id);
if(db.Model != null) // Here it breaks!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

The problem was that I used Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll 13.0.0.0 version

I updated it to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll 14.0.0.0 version and now all works fine.